# Django error with test module while running tests

Tags: python, django, django-tests

When i run `python manage.py tests` i get an error saying that some test module is not found.
I am using PyCharm, Django 2.1.4 and W10 on Ubuntu.

#### The error:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: projectname.projectname (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: projectname.projectname
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/loader.py", line 462, in _find_test_path
    package = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/loader.py", line 369, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'projectname.projectname'
```

#### What I've tried

1. `python manage.py runserver` and it runs just fine.
2. Add `projectname` to *INSTALLED_APPS*
3. Create and app called `tests`

#### My project structure

```
Django
│   ├── requirements.txt
│   └── projectname
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── manage.py
│       └── projectname
│           ├── apps
│           │   ├── accounts
│           │   │   ├── admin.py
│           │   │   ├── apps.py
│           │   │   ├── __init__.py
│           │   │   ├── migrations
│           │   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│           │   │   ├── models
│           │   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│           │   │   │   ├── profiles.py
│           │   │   │   └── users.py
│           │   │   ├── serializers
│           │   │   │   └── __init__.py
│           │   │   ├── tests.py
│           │   │   ├── urls.py
│           │   │   └── views
│           │   │       └── __init__.py
│           │   ├── __init__.py
│           ├── db.sqlite3
│           ├── __init__.py
│           ├── settings
│           │   ├── base.py
│           │   ├── development.py
│           │   ├── production.py
│           ├── static
│           ├── templates
│           ├── urls.py
│           └── wsgi.py
```

I just want to run my tests like in any other django project...
I have never encountered this problem before so any help is appreciated! :)

Comment: Can you try running `export PYTHONPATH=..;python manage.py test`?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Running ```export PYTHONPATH=path``` gives me an InvalidSyntax error.

Comment: You ran the whole command as stated above in your shell?

Comment: I thought it was python shell... Running that command still gives me the same error ```ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'projectname.projectname'```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, well...it turns out that changing the folder was the solutio, though i have projects working that share the same folder name so i don't really know what happend with this one.

**Before**:

```
Django
│   └── projectname
│       └── projectname
```

**After**:

```
Django
│   └── othername
│       └── projectname
```

Comment: Very normal solution, that in order to run tests you need to rename a folder,  django is such garbage.